# Why can't I access my template view when trying to register a user with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-login

I'm trying to implement a login functionality to a small Django project but when I go to the page with signup/signin form I get the 404 error. I am using Django default user model and auth forms.

here are the views:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})


def signin(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'homepage.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
            return render(request, 'signin.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, 'signin.html', {'form': form})


def log_out(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

here are the urls for my views:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='register'),
    path('signin/', views.signin, name='signup'),
    path('log_out/', views.log_out, name='log_out'),
]
```

project urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog_backend.urls'))
]
```

full error message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/signin/
Raised by:  blog_backend.views.post_detail
No Post matches the given query.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Comment: just guess to change your urlpattern to '/' instead of empty string sometimes cause 404.

Comment: Which URL gives you the 404? Please include the full error message - it should show you which URL patterns Django tried.

Comment: @erfanehtesham the home url works fine, its the authentication urls that I'm having problems with.

Comment: @Alasdair posted full error message, does not show patterns that Django tried, just 404, I read somewhere that templates for default django logging should be in a different directory, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: The error message is telling you that the request is being handled by `blog_backend.views.post_detail`, but you haven't shown that URL pattern in your question. If you have `include()`s in your main `urls.py`, then show that too.

Comment: Ignore the comment about `APPEND_SLASH` and `MIDDLEWARE` - that was a guess before you showed the full error message.

Comment: @Alasdair added the project scope urls

Comment: @Alasdair path('', include('blog_backend.urls')) this is where they are included

Comment: @Alasdair there's also this url: `path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),` but I didn't include it because it has nothing to do with logging.

Comment: `views.post_detail` is the view in the error message, so it's important to show where you use it in the URLs!

Comment: @Alasdair yes my bad.

Comment: @Alasdair do you have any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
path('signup/', views.signup, name='register'),
```

You have the URL pattern for `post_detail` above the `signup` pattern, so `signup/` is being handled by the `post_detail` view.

The `post_detail` view tries to find a post with `slug='signup'`, and gives a 404 error because it doesn't exist.

You can fix the problem by changing the `post_detail` URL so that it doesn't match `signup`, for example:

```
path('blog/<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
path('signup/', views.signup, name='register'),
```

Or switch the order of your URL patterns, so that the authentication URLs match first:

```
path('signup/', views.signup, name='register'),
path('signin/', views.signin, name='signup'),
path('log_out/', views.log_out, name='log_out'),
path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```